# When to do feature scaling? Before or after extraction?

Tags: mapping, feature-extraction

I am planning to do SVM classification on multidimensional sensor data. There are two classes and 13 sensors. Suppose that I want to extract features e.g. average, standard deviation etc. I read from somewhere that we need to do feature scaling before apply to SVM. I am wondering when I should do the scaling, before extracting features or after extracting features?

Comment: [This article](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_applying_feature_extraction_before_classification_using_SVM_improve_the_results) seems to say that doing feature extraction before building the SVM is desirable.

Comment: From the little machine learning I experienced in school, I remember analyzing the featured data was always a step before feeding into a classifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have read, and as already pointed out, you would:

1. do feature derivation
2. do feature normalization (scaling, deskewing if necessary, etc)
3. hand data to training/evaluating model(s).

For the example you mentioned, just to be clear: I assume you mean that you want to derive (the same) features for *each sample*, so that you have e.g. a mean feature, standard deviation feature, etc. *for each sample* - which is how it should be done. Normalization, in turn, has to be done *per feature over all samples*.